# How to display a messages each time you log in a container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to build an image that displays an echo message each time I log in the container
My Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM python:2 
ENTRYPOINT ['echo','hello you are inside the container']
```

The problem with this is that I get logged out of the container and I can't use the bash anymore

Comment: Not tried, but can you modify the relevant `.profile` to write the message when you attach?

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to several places, i.e. `/etc/profile.d`, but you need to make sure you run the shell as login shell, otherwise those scripts like /etc/profile and ~/.bashrc and so are not sourced.

For example:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN echo 'echo "welcome to the container"' > /etc/profile.d/welcome.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-l", "-c"]
```